# How to check for visibility of an element in Selenium using POM

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page where I need to check the visibility of a button and click it if present, Else skip the step. Using POM, I have tried the following approaches

#Approach -1

```
WebDriver driver;

WebElement searchForButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id=\"root\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div"));

public void buttonValidation() {
    searchForButton.click();
}
```

This approach would fail in the case when the button is not visible.

#Approach-2:

```
 @FindBy(xpath= "//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[1]/span[1]")
 private List<WebElement> elements;
    

 public boolean isElementPresent() {
        return elements != null && elements.size()>0 ; 
    }
    
 public void validateButton() throws InterruptedException {
        
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Boolean b = isElementPresent();
        
        if(b)
        {
            WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='root']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[1]"));  //JAVA NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
            btn.click();
        }
       }
```

Using this approach, java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown for **btn** search

What would be the correct approach?

Comment: in approach 1 you have an occurrence of searcForButton which should be searchForButton.

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo error. Edited the que :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this generic method:

```
public boolean clickVisible(By element){
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
        driver.findElement(element).click();
        return true;
    }catch (Throwable t){
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will get as a parameter a By locator for an element.
In case element found visible it will be clicked and `true` will be returned otherwise `false` will be returned.
So you can use it like this:

```
if(clickVisible(By.xpath("//*@id='root']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[1]"))){
    //your flow for case the element found visible and was clicked
}else{
    //your flow for alternative case
}
```

BTW it's strongly not recommended to use automatically generated locators like this `//*@id='root']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[1]` since they are highly breakable and very unreliable.
[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+locators+best+practices&oq=selenium+locators+&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j0l6j69i61.10482j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) presents [these](https://www.apress.com/it/blog/all-blog-posts/best-practices-for-choosing-locators-for-selenium/16169400) [two](https://screenster.io/selenium-locators-best-practices-7-helpful-tips-for-ui-testers/) as well as many other tutorials to learn how to choose a correct, reliable locators.

Comment: Thanks, what would be a better approach to find the element locators?

Comment: You should learn how to make them. It's not too difficult. Learn about XPath and CSS selectors. But the automatically generated are really bad.

Comment: I have added links to tutorials, however I did not checked them thoroughly

Comment: No, I am still getting Null Pointer Exception even if the element is present on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch for these kind of scenarios

```
try {
  WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='root']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[1]"));  //JAVA NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
  btn.click();
}
catch (Exception e) { /* do nothing */ }
```

Comment: Why do you think a try-catch approach is required for solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your `isElementPresent()` should take a list `args`, cause you are verifying

```
elements != null && elements.size()>0
```

so it should look like this :

```
public boolean isElementPresent(List<WebElement> elements) {
    return elements != null && elements.size()>0 ; 
}
```

and your **caller method** should look like this :-

```
public void validateButton() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    if(isElementPresent(elements))
    {
        WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='root']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[1]"));  //JAVA NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
        btn.click();
    }
}
```

your first approach can be wrapped inside a `try-catch block` :-

```
public void buttonValidation() {
    try {
        searchForButton.click();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```